# Is try_lock() +unlock() valid way to check whether boost::interprocess::file_lock is locked?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I need to check whether a file is locked using `boost::interprocess::file_lock`. I produced this, but I'm worried what it's gonna do:

```
bool DataCache::isLocked() const {
    bool res = lock_->try_lock();
    if(res)
        lock_->unlock();
    return res;
}
```

Is it a good idea? Isn't there a way to check it without locking it?

Comment: You realize this information is stale as soon as you unlock the lock. It's the same problem as checking if a file exists without opening it. The status can change immediately after your check. Don't base critical decisions on the results or you will introduce subtle race conditions.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Good point. The answer is no then, I guess, only valid way is to lock and do the stuff.

Comment: You create a interface functions for `tryLock` and `unlock` and use these?

Comment: @sehe: Posted what I meant as answer

Comment: @SimonKraemer Posted [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33526994/85371) to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this doesn't fit in a comment: You could create "interface functions" for `tryLock` and `unlock` externally.

e.g.:

```
bool DataCache::try_lock() const {
    return lock_->try_lock();
}

void DataCache::unlock() const {
    lock_->unlock();
}
```

Usage:

```
DataCache cache;
if(cache.try_lock())
{
    cache.doSomething();
    cache.unlock();
}
else
{
    //....
}
```

I'm not sure if the `const` will work here. I just copied it from the question code.

Comment: Yeah, this would be correct approach. The actual thing is that in my case, I realized I don't even know what was `locked` method meant for, but your answer is correct for anyone who will be about to do this.

Comment: Oh well. If this answers the question I'd suggest an idiom like `if (auto lk = try_lock(cache)) { ....  }` with RAII. Will post in a while (busy with kids)

Answer (score 9):

While the other answer is the key to not introducing a race condition, there is **no reason** to drop exception safety and error-resilience that comes from using the proper RAII wrappers like `std::lock_guard<>` and `std::unique_lock<>`.

You'd want to write:

```
if (auto lk = try_to_lock(mx)) {
    std::cout << "simple test\n";
} // automatically unlocks at scope exit
```

And you can. Here's my simple implementation:

```
template <typename Lockable>
std::unique_lock<Lockable> try_to_lock(Lockable& lockable) {
    return std::unique_lock<Lockable> (lockable, std::try_to_lock);
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e35947bbac253634)</kbd>**

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // demo
    std::mutex mx;

    if (auto lk = try_to_lock(mx)) {
        std::cout << "simple test\n";
    } // automatically unlocks at scope exit

    if (auto lk = try_to_lock(mx)) {
        std::cout << "yes\n";

        if (auto lk = try_to_lock(mx)) {
            std::cout << "oops?!\n"; // not reached
        } else {
            std::cout << "no recursive lock\n";
        }

        // but you can manipulate the lock if you insist:
        lk.unlock();

        if (auto lk = try_to_lock(mx)) {
            std::cout << "now we can lock again\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "oops?!\n"; // not reached
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
simple test
yes
no recursive lock
now we can lock again
```

Comment: PS. note that `unique_lock` is movable so you can make `try_lock_guard` trivially movable (will do when I come back)

Comment: +1 as RAII should be the preferred way. I didn't test it, but shouldn't `unique_lock` in combination `std::try_to_lock` do pretty much the same without a wrapper? `if (auto lk = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mx, std::try_to_lock)){...}`. This should also work if the `DataCache` provides the functions `lock`, `unlock` and `try_lock`

Comment: Oh hey. `try_to_lock` was new to me. Even more baffling, the explicit `bool`-conversion is also already there. Simplified my answer :)

Comment: We all learn something new everyday. I was also pretty surprised finding this. :-)